# Decomposition(or splitting) of compact operator.

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to know why the below is.

> Let $K:H\rightarrow H$ be a compact operator and $\delta>0$ be given. Then, there are two operators $T$ and $\epsilon$,
> $$ K=T+\epsilon$$
> where $T$ and $\epsilon$ satisfy $\dim({range(T)})<\infty$, $\|\epsilon\|_{H\rightarrow H}<\delta$ and $H$ is Hilbert space(it may serparable).

The $\| \cdot \|_{H\rightarrow H}$ is operator norm.

How can I show it ? Are $T$ and $\epsilon$ can be represented explicitly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be the closed unit ball of $H$. Then $K(B)$ is pre-compact and hence has a $\delta/2$-net $y_1, \dots, y_n$. Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{span}\{y_1, \dots, y_n\}$. Let $T = P \circ K$ and $\epsilon = K - T$. Then for $x$ with $\|x\| = 1$, pick $y_i$ such that $\|Kx - y_i\| < \delta/2$.

Notice that one has
$$\|Tx - y_i\| = \|PKx - y_i\| = \|P(Kx - y_i)\| \leq \|Kx - y_i\| < \delta/2$$

so that
$$ \|\epsilon x \| \leq \| Kx - y_i \| + \|Tx - y_i\| < \delta.$$

This shows that $\|\epsilon\| < \delta$ and $T$ clearly has finite dimensional range so we are done.

Comment: Can it be proved by using ball not net?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question but hopefully this answers it. The way one constructs a $\delta$-net of a precompact set $K$ is by considering the open cover $\{B(x, \delta): x \in K\}$ of $\bar{K}$ and extracting a finite subcover. The centers of the balls in this subcover will be the $\delta$-net. One could of course do this procedure by hand here to get the family of balls, derive the bound on each ball and use the fact they form a finite cover to write exactly the same proof. This would just be a slightly less efficient formulation imo.